# What is the meaning of the highlighted line down below ? It is from the book of Barack Obama, Dreams From My Father?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

**Stripped of language, stripped of work and routine—stripped even of the racial obsessions to which I'd become so accustomed and which I had taken(perversely) as a sign of my own maturation—I had been forced to look inside myself and had found only a great emptiness there."**

[image]

Comment: Have you looked up the meaning of ["strip"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/strip), the verb? What did it say? Have you looked up ["forced"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forced) and  "to look inside myself". What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: He has realised that without access to his language, work and racial obsessions, he feels empty and perhaps at a loss.